# insert image into a specific place of docx file using golang

Tags: go, docx

I am trying to fill a docx template dynamically using the golang package `"github.com/lukasjarosch/go-docx"`.

[image]

I can replace all the text fields accordingly with this code:

```
package main

import (
    docx "github.com/lukasjarosch/go-docx"
)

func main() {
    // some logic here

    replaceMap := docx.PlaceholderMap{
        "personName":            name,
        "companyName":           company_name,
        "cityName":              city_name,
        // .....
    }

    // read and parse the template docx
    doc, err := docx.Open("rental_contract_template.docx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // replace the keys with values from replaceMap
    err = doc.ReplaceAll(replaceMap)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // write out a new file
    err = doc.WriteToFile("replaced.docx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Now I want to insert an image at `{QRODE}`. I found out that unfortunately, this package does not provide this functionality. I am lacking the knowledge to work with `XML` directly. I am supposed to not use `"github.com/unidoc/unioffice"`.

How can I insert an image at that specific place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to try it ?

"github.com/nguyenthenguyen/docx"

this is example:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"

    "github.com/nguyenthenguyen/docx"
)

func main() {
    // Read from docx file
    r, err := docx.ReadDocxFile("./TestDocument.docx")
    // Or read from memory
    // r, err := docx.ReadDocxFromMemory(data io.ReaderAt, size int64)

    // Or read from a filesystem object:
    // r, err := docx.ReadDocxFromFS(file string, fs fs.FS)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    docx1 := r.Editable()
    // Replace like https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace
    docx1.Replace("old_1_1", "new_1_1", -1)
    docx1.Replace("old_1_2", "new_1_2", -1)
    docx1.ReplaceLink("http://example.com/", "https://github.com/nguyenthenguyen/docx", 1)
    docx1.ReplaceHeader("out with the old", "in with the new")
    docx1.ReplaceFooter("Change This Footer", "new footer")
    docx1.WriteToFile("./new_result_1.docx")

    docx2 := r.Editable()
    docx2.Replace("old_2_1", "new_2_1", -1)
    docx2.Replace("old_2_2", "new_2_2", -1)
    docx2.WriteToFile("./new_result_2.docx")

    // Or write to ioWriter
    // docx2.Write(ioWriter io.Writer)

    docx3 := r.Editable()
    //Currently only swaps apples for apples i.e. png to png, and not png to jpeg etc.
    docx3.ReplaceImage("word/media/image1.png", "./new.png")

    // replace the last image
    imageIndex := docx3.ImagesLen()
    docx3.ReplaceImage("word/media/image"+strconv.Itoa(imageIndex)+".png", "./new.png")
    docx3.WriteToFile("./new_result_3.docx")

    r.Close()
}
```

Comment: That is it. I tried this library and it worked. (At this point it worked only with png images)